# C# Menu strip text value

Tags: c#, toolstripmenu

I have a ToolStripMenu and a table where I have a column named `qcategory` char type. I want to create a query that selects only rows where `qcategory` is equal with ToolStripMenuItem selected. So I tried in this way:

```
String categorie;
        private void categoriaBToolStripMenuItem1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Simulare sim = new Simulare();
            sim.Show();
        }

        public void simulareExamenToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           categorie = simulareExamenToolStripMenuItem.Selected.ToString();
        }

        public string getCategorie()
        {
            return categorie;
        }
```

What I did there was to create a string named `categorie`. `simulareExamenToolStripMenuItem` is the button from the menu. Here I assigned to `categorie` the string value of item selected. In `categoriaBToolStripMenu1` I instantiated form `Simulare` where is the query. After that, I created a function that returns value of `categorie`. Then, in `Simulare` form, I instantiated `Elev` form (where is menu).

```
Elev elev = new Elev();
```

After that, in constructor I assing to `categorie` the value of `categorie` from `Elev` form.

```
String categorie = elev.getCategorie();
```

and do the query:

```
String dataA = "SELECT DISTINCT * FROM questions where `qcategory`  = '" + categorie + "' order by rand() limit 1";
```

My problem is that it doesn't read the menu item value right and I can't find the problem. All in all, I have to pass from form `Elev`, the string value of `categorie` and use it in form `Simulare`. Can anybody help me with that? Thanks!

**UPDATE!**
Now, this is crap. This is what I have in `Elev` form:

```
public void simulareExamenToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           //categorie = simulareExamenToolStripMenuItem.Selected.ToString();
            //SimulatorManager.Categorie = simulareExamenToolStripMenuItem.DropDownItems.ToString();
            foreach (ToolStripMenuItem subItem in simulareExamenToolStripMenuItem.DropDownItems) //dropdown is the name of the **parent** of the dropdown. Without your full code I can't tell you what to put there
                {
                    if(subItem.Checked)
                        {
                            SimulatorManager.Categorie = subItem.Text;
                        }
                }
        }

        private void categoriaBToolStripMenuItem1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Simulare sim = new Simulare();
            sim.Show();
        }
```

This is what I have in `Simulare` form:

```
String categorie = SimulatorManager.Categorie;
```

and in contructor:

```
String dataA = "SELECT DISTINCT * FROM questions where `qcategory`='" + categorie + "' order by rand() limit 1";
```

But is not showing rows where exist `CategoriaB`, it shows rows where value is `Categoria C`. On `Console.WriteLine(categorie)` it shows `Categoria C`, not `CategoriaB` as it should. (`Categoria C` is a value like `Categoria B` from `qcategory` column, but at the other row.)
**OMG!** Whatever subItem I would chose, it selects `Categoria C`..why???

**UPDATE 2**
This is what I have in `Elev` form:

```
public void simulareExamenToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (ToolStripMenuItem subItem in simulareExamenToolStripMenuItem.DropDownItems) 
                {
                    if(subItem.Checked)
                        {
                            SimulatorManager.Categorie = subItem.Text;
                        }
                }
        }

        private void categoriaBToolStripMenuItem1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Simulare sim = new Simulare();
            sim.Show();
        }

        private void categoriaCToolStripMenuItem1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Simulare sim = new Simulare();
            sim.Show();
        }
```

This is what I have in `Simulare` form:

```
public Simulare() // maine constructor
        {
            String categorie = SimulatorManager.Categorie;
            Console.WriteLine(categorie);
            dataA = "SELECT DISTINCT * FROM questions where `qcategory`='" + categorie + "' order by rand() limit 1";
        }
```

Whatever subItem I would choose, it selects rows which contains string value of last subItem from menu. (`Categoria C`) If I click on `Categoria B`, I receive questions from `Categoria C`.

Comment: Always use parameters to avoid SQL injection.  Should be `qcategory=@qcategory` and then provide the information in the cmd.Parameters collection.  Always, always, always.

Comment: Well, for example menu item is named `Categoria B` and in table, in column `qcategory` I have `Categoria B` value. But is not working..it doesn't select anything

Comment: How can I do that with Parameters? I'm not familiar

Comment: You want to pass `categorie` from *form simulare* to *form elev*?

Comment: @adricadar , converse, from elev to simulare

Comment: @HansPassant , can you be more specific? I mean I don't know what you mean

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Selected` property is a boolean, meaning `categorie` will always equal `"True"` or `"False"`. Check this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolstripitem.selected(v=vs.110).aspx)

A possible solution:

```
public void simulareExamenToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   ToolStripMenuItem senderMenuItem = sender as ToolStripMenuItem;
   if(senderMenuItem != null)
   {
      categorie = senderMenuItem.Text;
   }
}
```

This would work for all menu items, you just need to add it as the click handler for each one.

Or:

```
public void simulareExamenToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   categorie = "Something";
}
```

This solution would need each menu item to have a click event handler that is similar to this one.

**Edit**

You'll need to make sure the dropdown menu items can be checked(this is set via properties). When the button is clicked go through the dropdown menu and find the selected menu item.

```
public void simulareExamenToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   foreach(ToolStripMenuItem subItem in dropdown.DropDownItems) //dropdown is the name of the **parent** of the dropdown. Without your full code I can't tell you what to put there
   {
      if(subItem.Checked)
      {
         categorie = subItem.Text;
      }
   }
}
```

You should consider posting your full code as your question is not clear what you are trying to accomplish.

**Edit 2**

I decided to create my own project to try and show a full solution of what I think you're trying to achieve. [This](http://imgur.com/PF9gbTg) is what the Windows look like

Elev.cs

```
public partial class Elev : Form
{
    private string category = null;

    public Elev()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    //Attached to **each** sub item in the dropdown
    private void OnCategoryChecked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ToolStripMenuItem senderItem = sender as ToolStripMenuItem;

        //If the sender isn't a tool strip item OR it's alreadt checked do nothing
        if (senderItem != null && !senderItem.Checked)
        {
            //Un check the previously checked item
            foreach (ToolStripMenuItem item in this.toolStripDropDownButton1.DropDownItems)
            {
                item.Checked = false;
            }

            //Set it to checked so the user knows which is selected
            senderItem.Checked = true;

            //Set the category
            this.category = senderItem.Text;
        }
    }

    private void ExamineButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (category == null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Select a category first!");
        }
        else
        {
            Simulare sim = new Simulare(this.category);
            sim.Show();
        }
    }
}
```

Simulare.cs

```
public partial class Simulare : Form
{
    public Simulare()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.categoryTextBox.Text = "None";
    }

    public Simulare(string category)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.categoryTextBox.Text = category;
    }

    public string Category
    {
        get
        {
            return this.categoryTextBox.Text;
        }
        set
        {
            this.categoryTextBox.Text = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73230/discussion-between-diacu-paul-and-amura-cxg).